# Can a callback function be a closure?

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

```
getTotal() {
    let total = 0;
    this.results.forEach(result => {
        total += result.marks;
    })
    return total;
}
```

Is call back function inside forEach method be a closure as it is accessing the total variable outside its scope?

Comment: Meh, depends on how exactly you define "closure". In some sense, this does demonstrate closure, because those inner callback functions modify the outer variable `result`, but in a deeper sense I would say no, because there's no way to call those callbacks from outside the `getTotal` function. So there's no way to observe `total` once the function that it's defined in has finished executing, and the latter for me at least is the distinguishing feature of closures m

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's. Use `reduce` for folding:

```
 return this.results.reduce((total, result) => total + result.marks)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is closure. Your `anonymous cb` function has been declared in the same scope as a `total` variable and `anonymous cb` got an implicit`[[Environment]]` property, where your `total` variable is stored.
Check it here.
https://javascript.info/closure